# How to limit access to a different instance region in lightsail via firewall using VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, amazon-vpc, amazon-lightsail

I created Instance A and Instance B but I want to use VPC for my users to access Instance B only. Is it possible? .I found this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/scenario-restrict.html

I found this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/scenario-restrict.html but still confused how to connect VPS to light sail

Comment: What do you mean by "for my users to access Instance B only"? Who are your users and how are they connecting to Instance B -- is it via SSH, or is the instance running a web server? Can they currently access instance B successfully? How are you authenticating these "users", or are you referring to anyone (including unauthenticated people)? Please Edit your Question to add these details instead of answering in a comment. Tell us lots of stuff please!

Comment: The instance A and the instance B are in the same VPC or in different?, please describe with more details your question.